# Extra scrolling bar on Y axis on my HTML page

Tags: html, css, gsap

Hi I'm making a clone of website name (Miranda-paper portfolio), I used locomotive smooth scroll and gsap for animations everything was working fine but when I created page#2 another scroll bar start to appear on Y axis, I'm so confused why am I having this, So please can you guys take a look at my good and tell me what am I doing wrong here, Thanks.

```js
const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
  el: document.querySelector("#main"),
  smooth: true,
});

var tl = gsap.timeline();

tl.to("#page-1", {
  y: "100vh",
  scale: 0.6,
  duration: 0,
});

tl.to("#page-1", {
  y: "30vh",
  duration: 1,
  delay: 1,
});

tl.to("#page-1", {
  y: "0vh",
  rotate: 360,
  scale: 1,
  duration: 0.8,
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Domaine;
  src: url(./DomaineDispCondMedium.ttf);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#main {
  background-color: #222;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#page-1 {
  height: 110vh;

  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #bfb8ae;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#nav {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 30px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
}

#nav img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30%;
}

#nav h5 {
  font-size: 20px;

  width: 30%;
  font-weight: 100;
}

#nav i {
  width: 30%;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: right;
}

#elems {
  height: 430px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 40px 60px;
}

#elem1 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}

#elem1 h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: canopee;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#elem1 h4 span {
  background-color: #b43b12;
  color: #bfb8ae;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#elem1 p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: "Domaine";
  color: #656565;
}

#elem2 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 2px solid #585858;
  border-left: 2px solid #585858;
}

#elem2 h2 {
  font-family: canopee;
  font-size: 65px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

#elem2 h3 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-family: domaine;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: #383838;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

#elem3 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}

#elem3 h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: canopee;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#elem3 h4 span {
  background-color: #b43b12;
  color: #bfb8ae;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#elem3 p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: "Domaine";
  color: #656565;
}

#elem1 #image-div {
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#image-div:hover img {
  scale: 1.1;
}

#image-div img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: ease 0.4s;
}

#elem3 #image-div2 {
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#image-div2 img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;

  transition: ease 0.4s;
}

#image-div2:hover img {
  scale: 1.1;
}

#page-1 h1 {
  font-size: 37vw;
  letter-spacing: -25px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: canopee;
  background-color: #1c1c19;
  line-height: 600px;
  color: #bfb8ae;
  width: 96%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

#page-2 {
  height: 150vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #656565;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/locomotive-scroll@3.5.4/dist/locomotive-scroll.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@3.5.0/fonts/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="page-1">
            <div id="nav">
                <h5>Amsterdam, NL</h5>
                <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f2429f172d117fcee10e819/5f7f87c8b81a6e7a214312f0_header.svg"
                    alt="">
                <i class="ri-menu-line"></i>
            </div>
            <div id="elems">
                <div id="elem1">
                    <div id="image-div">
                        <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f9085a4041dd5427c5ac8ae/615d9672cc65f12c9ab25f21_thumbnail-small.jpeg?"
                            alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h4>AVRo | KO <span>NEW</span></h4>
                    <p>AvroKO is an award-winning global design firm, established itself as a global leader in
                        interior architecture for hospitality, restaurant and bars. </p>
                </div>
                <div id="elem2">
                    <h2>ALL WORK!</h2>
                    <h3>A Featured selection <br> the latest work - <br> of the last years.</h3>

                </div>
                <div id="elem3">
                    <div id="image-div2">
                        <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f9085a4041dd5427c5ac8ae/645b5439577bd35377de8c43_thumbnail-small.webp?"
                            alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h4>THE ROGER HUB<span>NEW</span></h4>
                    <p>The Roger Hub is an immersive web experience showcasing the tennis-inspired 'On' sneakers, a
                        collaboration born out of a partnership with the legendary Roger Federer.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1>MIRANDA</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="page-2">
            <div id="page2-left">
                <h2>INTERACTIVE <span>ARTIST</span></h2>
                <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f2429f172d117fcee10e819/605c6ce3bc0c7d1cd4ca847e_avatar-star-p-800.jpeg"
                    alt="">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis consequuntur vitae neque eius,
                    fugiat eaque at aliquid quam assumenda deleniti quaerat pariatur quibusdam minima accusantium, ab
                    enim ipsam esse. Doloribus.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="page2-right">
                <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f2429f172d117fcee10e819/605c62f4c78c4ba46a1268be_avatar-1-p-1600.jpeg"
                    alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/locomotive-scroll@3.5.4/dist/locomotive-scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/gsap.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-16esztaSRplJROstbIIdwX3N97V1+pZvV33ABoG1H2OyTttBxEGkTsoIVsiP1iaTtM8b3+hu2kB6pQ4Clr5yug=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```